# i want to convert 2nd row into column and ratings with each. 2 dimentional matrix

Tags: apache-pig

```
"User-ID";"ISBN";"Book-Rating"
"276725";"034545104X";"0"
"276726";"0155061224";"5"
"276727";"0446520802";"0"
```

Ouput would be like:

```
          "034545104X";"0155061224";"0446520802"
"276725"      "0"
"276726"                   "5"
"276727"                               "0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with below script in R.

## loading reader library

library(readr)

## reading CSV file with ';' as delimiter

BX_Book_Ratings <- read_delim("C:/Users/panch/Desktop/Lambton/Term_2_Fall_2017/2017F-T2 BDM 2013 - Data Collection Methods/project_03/dataset/BX-Book-Ratings.csv", ";", escape_double = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE)

## viewing data

View(BX_Book_Ratings)

## loading reshape2 library

library(reshape2)

## reading only few first rows from dataset

sample_data<-head(BX_Book_Ratings,30)

## generating matrix

d <- dcast( sample_data, User_ID ~ ISBN, value.var = "Book_Rating" )

## replacing NA with 0

d[is.na(d)] <- 0

## loading grid library to display data in table format

library(gridExtra)

## displaying table

grid.table(d)

## Storing output in CSV format

write.csv(d,"C:/Users/panch/Desktop/Lambton/Term_2_Fall_2017/2017F-T2 BDM 2013 - Data Collection Methods/project_03/dataset/output.csv")